# Stateful vs Stateless LSTM

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, lstm-stateful

I am trying to use LSTM in Keras and I am not sure whether I should used statefull or stateless LSTM. I have read many resources online but seem like they do not apply to my case.

I have a long predictor series `X=[X1,X2,....,Xn]` and a long response series `y=[0,0,...,1,1,0,...0]`. They have the same length and the response can only take value 1 or 0. My plan is to subsample the long predictor series and use the short series (length 4) to predict the response for the next 3 time points. So my training data look look this

```
[X1,X2,X3,X4],[y5,y6,y7]
[X2,X3,X4,X5],[y6,y7,y8]
...
```

If I use all these short series (samples) available, I think I should choose stateful. However, because there are a lot more 0 in `y` compared to 1, I will keep all the samples that has 1 in the short response series (ex: keep this sample `[y5=0,y6=1,y7=0]`) but I will randomly drop a lot of other samples just to make the data balance.

I am not sure whether I should use stateful here, since some short series may be very far away from each other.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to train a model using LSTM but you also want to remove some part of that time series data and be able to train the model at the same time.

Technically, you can achieve that simply just using stateful LSTM and chop your data into a same length then provide a **sample_weight**. For example, model.fit(x=data, y=class, sample_weight=np.array([1,1,0,0,0,1])), this will help you achieve what you want by removing index 2,3,4 without removing it from your data manually.

Normally, we modify loss instead of removing some part of time series out, something like wrongly classify class 1 will create 10 times loss than class 0.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you we can use sample weight of class weight to achieve the same effect. However my initial series are very long and it would take a long time to slice through the whole things. I wonder what happens if I drop many slices, should I still use stateful LSTM?

Comment: if you need to remove that much of data, it wouldn't be useful for you to use LSTM, LSTM trying to approximate a transition function from previous state to next state. So, if you remove a data in between two point, your data is disconnected, therefore you can not train the model anymore except you have some way to get a previous internal state of LSTM you can still train your model without any problem just specify the initial state of disconnected component you will good to go.

Comment: Moreover, you can use something like "for loop" and randomly setting weight for instances that have only 0 with probability P to 0. combine with loss modification can be quite effective. Or you can divide your data into small chunk regardless of continuity and initial state and train it, this may result in decreasing in performance.